# Determine time frame between mousePress and mouseMove for drag event in RxPy

Tags: python-3.6, rx-py

I am trying to achieve a drag and drop feature. The layout of my UI looks similar to below:

```
 --- --- ---
| 1 | 2 |   |
 --- ---  5 |
| 3 | 4 |   |
 --- --- ---
```

Boxes 1, 2, 3 and 4 are images and will have a white border surrounding it when selected by a user. This selection action is executed with a `left press`.

Box 5 displays some basic information of the selected image.

The images in Boxes 1, 2, 3 and 4 can be dragged and dropped into Box 5. On a successful dropped, a thumbnail of the dropped image will also be displayed in Box 5.

I have no issues executing a drag and drop action which is achieved using `RxPy`. My code for the drag and drop looks as follows:

```
drag_start = self.viewer.events \
    .filter(lambda ev: ev.type == MouseEventType.LeftPress)

drag_move = self.viewer.events \
    .filter(lambda ev: ev.type == MouseEventType.MouseMove)

drag = drag_start \
    .flat_map(lambda ev: \
        drag_move \
        .first()
    )

drag.subscribe(lambda ev: self.start_drag())

# and yes, i do not have a takeUntil mouse release event in my stream. this is done intentionally.
```

i have a thumbnail implemented in `start_drag` that follows wherever the cursor moves. i have left this part of the code out since it is not the highlight of the problem i am facing.

The problem i have is this. If I were to select an image, and no matter how much later I do a `mouse move`, `start_drag` will be fired and creates the thumbnail. if the `mouse move` event occurs after a certain time frame since the last `left press`, it should not be viewed as a drag event and not fire `start_drag`. Instead, an 'instant' `left press` + `mouse move` event will be seen as a drag event

what should be added to my event stream such that i will be able to determine the duration between the `left press` and `mouse move` events? subsequently, if this duration is more than the time frame, i will ignore and not fire `start_drag`. or is there a better solution to this problem?

`delay`, `debounce` basically either pushes or delays the stream and i cannot achieve what i want with those operators.